# Creating AVD in Eclipse for unlisted android device

Tags: eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have written an Android app using Eclipse Mars. I would like to test it on Nexus 5X and Nexus 6P Emulators. These devices are not listed in the 'create AVD' dialog's drop-down list.

I tried the 'device' tab and entered the size and other parameters of the device. The 'create device' button was enabled, but nothing happened when I clicked it. I have tried it several times now, waited for half an hour after clicking, tried it on a different computer, but nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in AVD Manager, you should look for an update to arrive and hope that it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think Eclipse AVD throws a tantrum if there's a space in the name.

Does the new name you put for your AVD have a space? Remove that and I think you should be good.

[image: Listing of two devices -- neither with a space in the name.]

See how my device's name doesn't have a space?